# Undefined reference to function name, C++

Tags: c++, linker, undefined-reference

I've seen this question asked a lot on this website, but trying the solutions offered on here have yet to work with my program.
So, I apologize for asking this question for the umpteenth time, but nothing is working for me.

I compile the following

```
g++ deque.cpp deque.h driver.cpp
```

and then get the error

```
/tmp/ccvkttRj.o: In function `main':
driver.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `Deque<int>::Deque()'
driver.cpp:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `Deque<int>::addBack(int const&)'
driver.cpp:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `Deque<int>::addFront(int const&)'
driver.cpp:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `Deque<int>::Deque(Deque<int> const&)'
driver.cpp:(.text+0xa7): undefined reference to `Deque<int>::addBack(int const&)'
driver.cpp:(.text+0xcf): undefined reference to `Deque<int>::isEmpty() const'
driver.cpp:(.text+0xe2): undefined reference to `Deque<int>::removeFront()'
driver.cpp:(.text+0x125): undefined reference to `Deque<int>::isEmpty() const'
driver.cpp:(.text+0x138): undefined reference to `Deque<int>::removeBack()'
driver.cpp:(.text+0x15f): undefined reference to `Deque<int>::~Deque()'
driver.cpp:(.text+0x16b): undefined reference to `Deque<int>::~Deque()'
driver.cpp:(.text+0x190): undefined reference to `Deque<int>::~Deque()'
driver.cpp:(.text+0x1a1): undefined reference to `Deque<int>::~Deque()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As far as I can tell, I'm using #include and #ifndef in the appropriate places, my method signatures are the same in my all my files.  But I have to be wrong otherwise I wouldn't be getting this error.

Here is my program for a deque:

1. the header

   ```
   #ifndef DEQUE_H
   #define DEQUE_H
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   template <class Object>
   class Deque
   {
    public:
     Deque(); // Constructor.
     Deque(const Deque &rhs); // Copy constructor.
     ~Deque(); // Destructor.

     bool isEmpty() const; // Is deque empty.
     int size() const; // Returns # of deque nodes.
     const Object &getFront() const; // Retrieve front node.
     const Object &getBack() const; // Retrieve tail node.

     void clear(); // Clears all nodes from deque.
     void addFront(const Object &obj); // Add a new node to the front.
     void addBack(const Object &obj); // Add a new node to the rear.
     Object removeFront(); // Remove front node.
     Object removeBack(); // Remove rear node.

     const Deque &operator=(const Deque &rhs); // Assignment.

    private:
     struct DequeNode
     {
       Object item;
       DequeNode *next;
       DequeNode *prev;
     };
     DequeNode *front;
     DequeNode *back;
   };

   #endif
   ```
2. the cpp

   ```
   #include "deque.h"

   template <class Object>
   Deque<Object>::Deque() // Constructor.
   {
     front = back = NULL;
   }

   template <class Object>
   Deque<Object>::Deque(const Deque &rhs) // Copy constructor.
   {
     front = back = NULL;
     *this = rhs;
   }

   template <class Object>
   Deque<Object>::~Deque()  // Destructor.
   {
     clear();
   }

   template <class Object>
   bool Deque<Object>::isEmpty() const // Check if deque is empty.
   {
     return front == NULL;
   }

   template <class Object>
   int Deque<Object>::size() const // Returns # of nodes.
   {
     int i = 0;
     for (DequeNode *ptr = front; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next)
       ++i;

     return i;
   }

   template <class Object>
   const Object &Deque<Object>::getFront() const // Retrieve front node.
   {
     if (isEmpty())
       throw "empty queue";

     return front->item;
   }

   template <class Object>
   const Object &Deque<Object>::getBack() const // Retrieve rear node.
   {
     if (isEmpty())
       throw "empty queue";

     return back->item;
   }

   template <class Object>
   void Deque<Object>::addFront(const Object &obj) // Add a new node to the front.
   {
     DequeNode *newPtr = new DequeNode; // Allocate the node in memory.
     newPtr->item = obj; // Insert obj.
     newPtr->next = front; // What once was front will become next.
     newPtr->prev = NULL; // Front node's prev is always NULL.

     if (isEmpty()) // If empty back points to the same as front.
       back = newPtr;
     else
       front->prev = newPtr; // The old front now points the new insert.

     front = newPtr; // Front now points to the new insert.
   }

   template <class Object>
   void Deque<Object>::addBack(const Object &obj) // Add a new node to the back.
   {
     DequeNode *newPtr = new DequeNode; // Allocate the node in memory.
     newPtr->item = obj; // Insert obj.
     newPtr->next = NULL; // The last node always points to null.
     newPtr->prev = back; // Inserting back, so point to what once was the last node.

     if (isEmpty()) // If empty front points to the same as back.
       front = newPtr;
     else
       back->next = newPtr; // Old back needs to point to new insert, not NULL.

     back = newPtr; // Back now points to the new insert.
   }

   template <class Object>
   Object Deque<Object>::removeFront() // Remove front node.
   {
     Object frontItem = getFront(); // Save what will be removed, so it can be returned.
     DequeNode *toDelete = front; // What will be deleted.

     if (front == back) // Only 1 item in the deque.
       front = back = NULL;
     else
       {
         front = front->next; // Move the next node up.
         front->prev = NULL; // Front node always points to NULL.
       }
     delete toDelete; // Goodbye what once was front;

     return frontItem;
   }

   template <class Object>
   Object Deque<Object>::removeBack() // Remove back/last node.
   {
     Object backItem = getBack(); // Save what will be removed, so it can be returned.
     DequeNode *toDelete = back; // What will be deleted.

     if (front == back) // Only 1 item in the deque.
       front = back = NULL;
     else
       {
         back = back->prev; // Move back up the list.
         back->next = NULL; // Last node always points to NULL.
       }
     delete toDelete; // Goodbye what once was back.

     return backItem;
   }

   template <class Object>
   const Deque<Object> &Deque<Object>::operator=(const Deque &rhs) // Assignment op.
   {
     if (this != &rhs) // Avoid self assignment.
       {
         clear(); // Not sure why clear, I'll have to come back to this.
         for (DequeNode *ptr = rhs.front; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next)
       addBack(ptr->item);
       }

     return *this;
   }
   ```
3. main

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include "deque.h"

   using namespace std;

   int main( ) {
    Deque<int> deque1;
    int item;

    for ( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
      deque1.addBack( j );
    for ( int j = 5; j < 10; j++ )
      deque1.addFront( j );

    Deque<int> deque2 = deque1;
    deque2.addBack( 10 );

    cout << "deque1: " << endl;
    while ( !deque1.isEmpty( ) )
      cout << deque1.removeFront( ) << endl;

    cout << "deque2: " << endl;
    while ( !deque2.isEmpty( ) )
      cout << deque2.removeBack( ) << endl;
   }
   ```

Comment: I knew a compiler that could do that, but it required a cxx_repository directory and frankly, it was not a good idea :)

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand.  According to the FAQ in that linked question, I'm supposed to add a specifier after every method in my cpp file?  For example in my cpp if I put under my constructor "template Deque<int>::Deque();" then for addBack I put "template void  Deque<int>::addBack(const int &obj);" and it makes the errors go away.  But this seems horribly inefficient, and seems to defeat the purpose of the ambiguity of the template.  Am I just misunderstanding how template is used?